# edoc not generating all documentation types in hrl file?

Tags: erlang

I currently have three files:

**tempfile.hrl**

```
-export_type([temptype/0]).
-type temptype() :: string().
%% blah blah documentation
```

**tempfile.erl**

```
-module(tempfile).

... more code, but no references to the temptype() type.
```

**random.erl**

```
-module(random).
%% @headerfile "tempfile.hrl"
-include("tempfile.hrl").

-spec random() -> tempfile:temptype().
```

However when using edoc, none of the documentation for `temptype()` appears. A hyperlink to `tempfile.html#temptype` appears, but it links to nowhere. I even tried to use `-export_type` but that didn't work... What could be the issue? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

temptype() is not part of the module tempfile.

What you can do is to include the declaration into the tempfile module.

```
-export_type([temptype/0]).
-type temptype() :: string().
```

You don't have to have a tempfile.hrl then.

=>

tempfile.erl

```
-module(tempfile).
-export_type([temptype/0]).
-type temptype() :: string().
```

random.erl

```
-module(random).

-spec random() -> tempfile:temptype().
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do want to keep the header file separate, the generic [`@headerfile` tag](http://erlang.org/doc/apps/edoc/chapter.html#generic-tags) can be used to import tags from an Erlang file like this:

**tempfile.erl**

```
-module(tempfile).

%%% @headerfile tempfile.hrl
... more code, but no references to the temptype() type.
```